# How to schedule django crons?

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, django-cron

I have a cron which I have written using django-cron:

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule

class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'statuscheck.my_cron_job'

    def do(self):
       print ("hello")
```

It works, as when the command `python manage.py runcrons` is run twice in a row, only one output is provided unless the 1 minute has lapsed

My question is, how do i then schedule that command to be executed for example 3 times a week?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just change the number of minutes, given there are 60 minutes in an hour, 24 hours in a day and 7 days in a week, you could do something like :

```
RUN_EVERY_MINS = 60 * 24 * 7 / 3 # three times a week
```

About the issue mentioned in your comment, I think you should use CRON.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

You could add this line in `/etc/crontab` (replace `/path/to` by real path) :

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/manage.py && /usr/bin/python manage.py runcrons
```

This will run your script every minute.

**Note** that you won't see "hello" on your terminal's session. If you want to see the CRON output you could redirect it to a file :

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/manage.py && /usr/bin/python manage.py runcrons >> /tmp/django_cron.log
```

Comment: Hi @Loïc, thank you for taking your time to reply :) When I run the cron, it only executes once, it doesn't  execute every minute. 
What the application currently does it executes once and if I try to execute the same command again, it doesnt work unless 1 minute has lapsed - do i need another scheduling program to run my python manage.py runcrons ` ?

Comment: Hi @theMicroGirl I've edited my answer to answer your comment.

Answer (score -2):

1. One thing to do crontab is using django celery.
2. Do the setup in celery_config.py, Write all the configuration settings in this file
   Example:

   from celery.schedules import crontab
   CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
   'client-gets-email-on-new-message': {
       'task': 'apps.app_name.tasks.send_email',
       'schedule': crontab(minute="*")
   },
   }
3. Finally configuration settings.py file

   INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django_celery_results',
   'django_celery_beat'
   )